# Store website username/password on Elinks for Ubuntu

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, passwords, ubuntu-16.04, elinks

I'm using Elinks 0.12pre6 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Yes, I know it's old. This is an old computer that I use for a couple of specific purposes and it works great. It's not my main computer.

I use Elinks to upload/download stuff from a storage account I have, since it's faster and less resource demanding than using a graphic browser like Chrome.

The think is that, every once in a while, I have to enter my username and password to access my account, and I was wondering if there's a way to store this information on Elinks so I don't have to enter it every time.

I tried searching for this on the internet, but none of the results I found were relevant. Help, anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set document.browse.forms.show_formhist to 1 ?